# How to selectively make a colour in three.js canvas transparent?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, alpha

I have a three.js canvas generated from liquidfun.js.

[image: See here].

For some reason, the canvas is not transparent. Is there a way to selectively make a color in the canvas fully transparent(in this case, the whitish background),after having painted the whole canvas? I tried setting `context.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)` but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably need to post some code.

If you're using the same code from the liquidfun website it's not using WebGL directly it's using three.js so you'd need to set the color by finding the three.js renderer and calling [`renderer.setClearColor`](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer). You'd also need to initialize three.js with an alpha channel when you create your rendered

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
```

Example:

```js
// shouldnt be a global :(
var particleColors = [
  new b2ParticleColor(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff), // red
  new b2ParticleColor(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff), // green
  new b2ParticleColor(0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff), // blue
  new b2ParticleColor(0xff, 0x8c, 0x00, 0xff), // orange
  new b2ParticleColor(0x00, 0xce, 0xd1, 0xff), // turquoise
  new b2ParticleColor(0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff), // magenta
  new b2ParticleColor(0xff, 0xd7, 0x00, 0xff), // gold
  new b2ParticleColor(0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff) // cyan
];
var container;
var world = null;
var threeRenderer;
var renderer;
var camera;
var scene;
var objects = [];
var timeStep = 1.0 / 60.0;
var velocityIterations = 8;
var positionIterations = 3;
var test = {};
var projector = new THREE.Projector();
var planeZ = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 0);
var g_groundBody = null;

var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

function printErrorMsg(msg) {
  var domElement = document.createElement('div');
  domElement.style.textAlign = 'center';
  domElement.innerHTML = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(domElement);
}

function initTestbed() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70
    , windowWidth / windowHeight
    , 1, 1000);

  try {
    threeRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
  } catch( error ) {
    printErrorMsg('<p>Sorry, your browser does not support WebGL.</p>'
                + '<p>This testbed application uses WebGL to quickly draw'
                + ' LiquidFun particles.</p>'
                + '<p>LiquidFun can be used without WebGL, but unfortunately'
                + ' this testbed cannot.</p>'
                + '<p>Have a great day!</p>');
    return;
  }

  threeRenderer.setClearColor(0, 0);
  threeRenderer.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 0;
  camera.position.z = 100;
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  document.body.appendChild( this.threeRenderer.domElement);

  this.mouseJoint = null;

  // hack
  renderer = new Renderer();
  var gravity = new b2Vec2(0, -10);
  world = new b2World(gravity);
  Testbed();
}

function testSwitch(testName) {
  ResetWorld();
  world.SetGravity(new b2Vec2(0, -10));
  var bd = new b2BodyDef;
  g_groundBody = world.CreateBody(bd);
  test = new window[testName];
}

function Testbed(obj) {
  // Init world
  //GenerateOffsets();
  //Init
  var that = this;
  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (test.Keyboard !== undefined) {
      test.Keyboard(String.fromCharCode(event.which) );
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (test.KeyboardUp !== undefined) {
      test.KeyboardUp(String.fromCharCode(event.which) );
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    var p = getMouseCoords(event);
    var aabb = new b2AABB;
    var d = new b2Vec2;

    d.Set(0.01, 0.01);
    b2Vec2.Sub(aabb.lowerBound, p, d);
    b2Vec2.Add(aabb.upperBound, p, d);

    var queryCallback = new QueryCallback(p);
    world.QueryAABB(queryCallback, aabb);

    if (queryCallback.fixture) {
      var body = queryCallback.fixture.body;
      var md = new b2MouseJointDef;
      md.bodyA = g_groundBody;
      md.bodyB = body;
      md.target = p;
      md.maxForce = 1000 * body.GetMass();
      that.mouseJoint = world.CreateJoint(md);
      body.SetAwake(true);
    }
    if (test.MouseDown !== undefined) {
      test.MouseDown(p);
    }

  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    var p = getMouseCoords(event);
    if (that.mouseJoint) {
      that.mouseJoint.SetTarget(p);
    }
    if (test.MouseMove !== undefined) {
      test.MouseMove(p);
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    if (that.mouseJoint) {
      world.DestroyJoint(that.mouseJoint);
      that.mouseJoint = null;
    }
    if (test.MouseUp !== undefined) {
      test.MouseUp(getMouseCoords(event));
    }
  });


  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

  testSwitch("TestWaveMachine");

  render();
}

var render = function() {
  // bring objects into world
  renderer.currentVertex = 0;
  if (test.Step !== undefined) {
    test.Step();
  } else {
    Step();
  }
  renderer.draw();

  threeRenderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

var ResetWorld = function() {
  if (world !== null) {
    while (world.joints.length > 0) {
      world.DestroyJoint(world.joints[0]);
    }

    while (world.bodies.length > 0) {
      world.DestroyBody(world.bodies[0]);
    }

    while (world.particleSystems.length > 0) {
      world.DestroyParticleSystem(world.particleSystems[0]);
    }
  }
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 0;
  camera.position.z = 100;
};

var Step = function() {
  world.Step(timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
};

/**@constructor*/
function QueryCallback(point) {
  this.point = point;
  this.fixture = null;
}

/**@return bool*/
QueryCallback.prototype.ReportFixture = function(fixture) {
  var body = fixture.body;
  if (body.GetType() === b2_dynamicBody) {
    var inside = fixture.TestPoint(this.point);
    if (inside) {
      this.fixture = fixture;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  threeRenderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function getMouseCoords(event) {
  var mouse = new THREE.Vector3();
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / windowWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / windowHeight) * 2 + 1;
  mouse.z = 0.5;

  projector.unprojectVector(mouse, camera);
  var dir = mouse.sub(camera.position).normalize();
  var distance = -camera.position.z / dir.z;
  var pos = camera.position.clone().add(dir.multiplyScalar(distance));
  var p = new b2Vec2(pos.x, pos.y);
  return p;
}
```

```css
body {
        font-family: Monospace;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: red;  /* just in case image doesn't load */
        background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/v38pV.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/liquidfun.js"></script>

  <!-- testbed code !-->
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/renderer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/testbed.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/utils.js"></script>

  <!-- tests !-->
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testDamBreak.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testDrawingParticles.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testElasticParticles.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testImpulse.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testLiquidTimer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testParticles.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testRigidParticles.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testSoup.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testSoupStirrer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testSparky.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testSurfaceTension.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testTheoJansen.js"></script>
  <script src="https://google.github.io/liquidfun/testbed/testbed/tests/testWaveMachine.js"></script>

  <body onload="initTestbed()"></body>

  <div style="position:absolute;float:right;z-index:1;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;background:white">

      <select id="tests" onchange="testSwitch(this.value)">
        <option value="TestDamBreak">Dam Break</option>
        <option value="TestDrawingParticles">Drawing Particles</option>
        <option value="TestElasticParticles">Elastic Particles</option>
        <option value="TestImpulse">Impulse</option>
        <option value="TestLiquidTimer">Liquid Timer</option>
        <option value="TestParticles">Particles</option>
        <option value="TestRigidParticles">Rigid Particles</option>
        <option value="TestSoup">Soup</option>
        <option value="TestSoupStirrer">Soup Stirrer</option>
        <option value="TestSparky">Sparky</option>
        <option value="TestSurfaceTension">SurfaceTension</option>
        <option value="TestTheoJansen">Theo Jansen</option>
        <option value="TestWaveMachine" selected="selected">Wave Machine</option>
      </select>

  </div>
```

If on the other hand you are using WebGL directly then by default a canvas has alpha and its clear color is 0,0,0,0 so if you're not seeing transparency that's something you've done on your own code or whatever library you're using to setup WebGL.

Note: There are other issues you should be aware of with [WebGL, canvas and transparency](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Yes, I am using the liquidfun code from the website(removed the mouse event listeners and added some of my own code in the testbed and renderer codes). Setting {alpha: true} in the initializing statement and making the alpha argument 0 in the renderer.setClearColor method just did the trick for me. Thanks a lot again, and I am indebted.